# Expansion of $\,n/(n-m)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am reading a textbook containing the expression

$$\frac{n}{n-m}=1+\frac{m}{n}+\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^2+\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^3+\ldots$$

where $m, n$ are positive integers. I do not understand why the expression is true, but I suppose I am missing something obvious. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint : If you divide numerator and denominator by $n$ , you will notice a formula for an infinite geomtetric sum.

Comment: well, this is only true if $|m|<|n|$.

Comment: See [Geometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Comment: Thank you Peter, got it now.